# SCM Poll in jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Wanted to accommodate scheduled build starting 12AM every 3 hrs till 3PM on every weekday(mon-fri). It should be triggered build only if anything is committed into github repository.

Please provide the exact code as few code is working for multi-branch but not for above schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry what do you mean by the scheduled "build"?

1. Do you want the Multi-Branch to check for more branches on your given interval?

If so you can only do it by "Scan Multibranch Pipeline with defaults Triggers"

2. Do you want to issue a build on the branch when there is change on it?

Noted that the option in

the mult-branch folder > "Scan Multibranch Pipeline with defaults Now" and get all current branches > status > the jobs > **View** Configuration

is read only.

So, to alter the option, from https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33900?focusedCommentId=326181&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-326181
, I think you should use the Jenkinsfile to do theSCM for every job.

So, for all jobs you need to configure for SCM poll,
include a Jenkinsfile on Git for each of them (Don't forget to install the pipeline-model-definition plugin and all its dependent plugins):

```
pipeline {
  triggers {
        pollSCM('H 0-15/3 * * H(1-5)')
           }
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
            echo 'Building.. or whatever'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

That should do the job, at least it works for me``

Hope it helps

Comment: We have used the same structure. Its working in normal pipeline job. But not working with multibranch pipiline jobs

Comment: Sorry that I thought multi-branch has that option too. I am working on it

Comment: Answer Edited, please check

Comment: Please mark this answer the best if it successfully solves your problem or tell me if it does not work

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you or it is a correct answer. Or you may tell me if it does not work