# What does the pollSCM trigger refer to in this Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins

Consider the following setup using Jenkins 2.176.1:

- A new pipeline project named `Foobar`
- `Poll SCM` as (only) build trigger, with: `H/5 * * * *` ... under the assumption that this refers to the SCM configured in the next step
- `Pipeline script from SCM` with SCM `Git` and a working Git repository URL

  - Uncheck `Lightweight checkout` because of [JENKINS-42971](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42971) and [JENKINS-48431](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48431) (I am using build variables in the *real* project and `Jenkinsfile`; also this may affect how `pollSCM` works, so I include this step here)
- Said repository contains a simple `Jenkinsfile`

The `Jenkinsfile` looks approximately like this:

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers { pollSCM 'H/5 * * * *' }
    stages {
        stage('Source checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout(
                    [
                        $class: 'GitSCM',
                        branches: [],
                        browser: [],
                        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                        extensions: [],
                        submoduleCfg: [],
                        userRemoteConfigs: [
                            [
                                url: 'git://server/project.git'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                )
                stash 'source'
            }
        }
        stage('OS-specific binaries') {
            parallel {
                stage('Linux') {
                    agent { label 'gcc && linux' }
                    steps {
                        unstash 'source'
                        echo 'Pretending to do a build here'
                    }
                }
                stage('Windows') {
                    agent { label 'windows' }
                    steps {
                        unstash 'source'
                        echo 'Pretending to do a build here'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding so far was that:

1. a change to the `Jenkinsfile` (not the whole repo) triggers the pipeline on any registered agent (or as configured in the pipeline project).
2. said agent (which is random) uses the `pollSCM` trigger in the `Jenkinsfile` to trigger the pipeline stages.

   - But where does the `pollSCM` trigger poll (what SCM repo)? And if it's a random agent then how can it reasonably detect *changes* across poll runs?
3. then the stages are being executed on the agents as allocated ...

Now I am confused what refers to what. So here my questions (all interrelated which is why I keep it together in one question):

- The pipeline project polls the SCM *just* for the `Jenkinsfile` or for *any* changes? The repository in my case is the same (for `Jenkinsfile` and source files to build binaries from).

  - If the (project-level) polling triggers at any change rather than changes to the Jenkinsfile
- Does the `pollSCM` trigger in the `Jenkinsfile` somehow automagically refer to the `checkout` step?

  - Then ... what would happen, would I have multiple `checkout` steps with differing settings?
  - What determines what repository (and what contents inside of that) gets polled?
- ... or is this akin to the `checkout scm` shorthand and `pollSCM` actually refers to the SCM configured in the pipeline project and so I can shorten the `checkout()` to `checkout scm` in the `steps`?

Unfortunately the user handbook didn't answer any of those questions and `pollSCM` has a total of four occurrences on a single page within the entire handbook.

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a crack at this one:

> The pipeline project polls the SCM just for the Jenkinsfile or for any
> changes? The repository in my case is the same (for Jenkinsfile and
> source files to build binaries from).

The pipeline project will poll the repo for ANY file changes, not just the Jenkinsfile.  A Jenkinsfile in the source repo is common practice.

> If the (project-level) polling triggers at any change rather than
> changes to the Jenkinsfile Does the pollSCM trigger in the Jenkinsfile
> somehow automagically refer to the checkout step?

Your pipeline will be executed when a change to the repo is seen, and the steps are run in the order that they appear in your Jenkinsfile.

> Then ... what would happen, would I have multiple checkout steps with
> differing settings?

If you defined multiple repos with the checkout step (using multiple checkout SCM calls) then the main pipeline project repo would be polled for any changes and the repos you define in the pipeline would be checked out regardless of whether they changed or not.

> What determines what repository (and what contents inside of that)
> gets polled? ... or is this akin to the checkout scm shorthand and
> pollSCM actually refers to the SCM configured in the pipeline project
> and so I can shorten the checkout() to checkout scm in the steps?

`pollSCM` refers to the pipeline project's repo. The entire repo is cloned unless the project is otherwise configured (shallow clone, lightweight checkout, etc.).

Comment: thanks. What are the excluded and included regions for then, if "ANY" changes are being considered? Also, the way it sounds the `checkout scm` would be sufficient as long as the `Jenkinsfile` sits next to the other source code, right? ... probably also refers to the pipeline project settings for the SCM then. Awarding the bounty to you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the excluded and included regions.  Is that something you see when creating a pipeline project?  Sorry, we usually use GitHub org folders or multi-branch pipelines.


Yes, checkout scm with no options will refer to the project's scm when the jenkinsfile is in the same repo as the source code. But unless you are checking out some other repo, you shouldn't need to do checkout scm since it has already cloned the repo to get the jenkinsfile.  You are doing a redundant checkotu at that point.

Comment: correct, this can be configured in the project. You may have to look at the advanced configuration, though. Don't have a Jenkins instance handy right now, but I think that's what it was called.

Comment: Yeah, I tried making a pipeline project and I don't see anything in regards to include or exclude.  Might be part of a plugin you have installed. When I have seen it in the past it was usually pertaining to including or excluding branches from a multi-branch pipeline.  The project would then only look for changes in the included branch or in every branch except the excluded ones.

Answer (score 0):

The [trigger](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) defined as `pollSCM` polls the [source-control-management (SCM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), at the repository and branch in which this `jenkinsfile` itself (and other code) is located.

> For Pipelines which are integrated with a source such as GitHub or BitBucket, triggers may not be necessary as webhooks-based integration will likely already be present. The triggers currently available are `cron`, `pollSCM` and `upstream`.

It works for a [multibranch-pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#creating-a-multibranch-pipeline) as trigger to execute the pipeline.

When Jenkins polls the SCM, exactly this repository and branch, and detects a change (i.e. new commit), then this Pipeline (defined in `jenkinsfile`) is executed.

Usually then the following *SCM Step* [`checkout`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-check-out-from-version-control) will be executed, so that the specified project(s) can be built, tested and deployed.

See also:

- [SCM Poll in jenkins multibranch pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388927/scm-poll-in-jenkins-multibranch-pipeline)
- SehllHacks(2020): [Jenkins: Scan Multibranch Pipeline Without Build](https://www.shellhacks.com/jenkins-scan-multibranch-pipeline-without-build/)